# How to split a complex html table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some webpages using bs4. I get the tables from the webpage as follows:

```
tables_list = soup.find_all("table")
```

However, I have some complex tables which contains multiple small table sections. I have provided the source code for the table here:

```
https://ufile.io/tee2c
```

Is there a way to split such a table into smaller table sections so that I can parse each one into its own dataframe? Thanks.

Here's my code thus far using python html extractor (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-table-extractor/1.3.0)

```
# table_doc => source code provided at https://ufile.io/tee2c 

extractor = Extractor(str(table_doc))
extractor.parse()
list_of_lists = extractor.return_list()
new_list = []  

# some cleanup 
for row in list_of_lists:
    stripped_list = [item.strip() for item in row]
    if len(set(stripped_list))==1 or any([x for x in stripped_list if len(x)>200]): # skip any item with > 200 characters, its probably some paragraph string and hence not a valid table item
        continue
    new_list.append(stripped_list)    



df = pandas.DataFrame(new_list)  

"""need to understand how to get this dataframe in a more structured format; for complex tables (e.g. the one provided at https://ufile.io/tee2c), this df contains content from multiple table 'sections' """
```

Comment: Indeed you can. But what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried parsing the entire tables using pandas read_html and I can generate dataframes corresponding to each table. However, each table I extract is by definition any content within <table> tag. So the resultant dataframe in the case such as the complex table I have provided at the link is highly unstructured. That is why I feel the table needs to broken down at the source code level itself when extracting with beautiful soup. I am stuck here and have no idea how to break such complex tables since each table has multiple table sections which are not aligned. Any pointers would be much app

Comment: Could you post your code? We can help you debug.

Comment: Sure, @COLDSPEED, thank you. To clarify, I have been experimenting with few different libraries in addition to pandas read_html. I am appending my code above in the original question description.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, please let me know if there is anything else I should provide. Looking forward to your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking at the source code. Can you tell me what exactly you want to do with the inner tables? You want to ignore them?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thanks for looking. I want to create a pandas dataframe corresponding to each of those tables. In that way, each one will have their corresponding column alignments retained.

Comment: Okay. On closer inspection, that html page is a goddamn mess. There's one huge table representing all rows, and no way to tell how to distinguish different tables. This is definitely _not_ how one should create a html page. Whoever gave you this donkey's work is clearly messing with you. It'd be much faster to just use some sort of parser to auto extract the text from the page, whereafter you massage the data into a usable form.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Aside from this specific example, for the sake of understanding, is there some general process on how to consider splitting such complex tables (assuming its a properly written html table)?

Comment: Yes. There definitely would. If each table was wrapped inside its _own_ <table> tag. It would be possible.